# How do you verify input is not null, whitespace or integer?

Tags: javascript, arrays, validation, null, whitespace

I have the following code verifying that my text boxes are not null, which is working great.  What else would I have to add to also verify they are not whitespace or contain ANY integers?

```
function verifyDados() { 
function nullCheck() {
    var x = $(".dadosDoTutor");
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++)
    if (x[i].value === '') {
        return 0;
    }
}
if (nullCheck() === 0) {
    alert ('Você ainda não tenham completado o preenchimento da tabela Dados do Tutor. Faz favor, verifique que você respondeu a cada pergunta e submeter mais uma vez.');
}
```

Note: for the whitespace issue, I tried adapting some "str = jQuery.trim(str);" type solutions that I found trying to research this topic, but couldn't get them either travel through my array, or work for an unknown reason.

thanks for any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll want to trim the input and check against "" to see if it's got stuff in it, then just use string.match(/\d+/g); to see if it contains a number.

Answer (score 0):

For this, `false` is it fails, `true` is it passes.

```
 function check(input){
    var possible_integers = "0123456789".split(""); //if it has any of these, it fails
    if(input === null){
        return false;
    }
    else if(input.trim() === ""){
        return false;
    }
    else{
        for(var i = 0; i < possible_integers.length; i++){
            if(input.indexOf(possible_integers[i]) !== -1){
                    return false;
            }
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ended up using a hybrid of the two above combined with my own.

```
function verifyDados() {  
function nullCheck() {
    var x = $(".dadosDoTutor");
    var y = /\d+/g;
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++)
    if (y.test(x[i].value) === true || x[i].value.trim() === "") {
        return 0;
    }
}
if (nullCheck() === 0) {
    alert ('Você ainda não tenham completado o preenchimento da tabela Dados do Tutor. Faz favor, verifique que você respondeu a cada pergunta e submeter mais uma vez.');
}
```